# How can I fix this linked list output?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{

    int sayi;
    struct node* sonraki;



};

struct node* baslangic=NULL;


struct node* olustur(int sayi){

    struct node* yenidugum=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    yenidugum->sayi=sayi;
    yenidugum->sonraki=NULL;

    return yenidugum;



}

void sonaekle(int sayi){

    struct node* sonaeklenecek=olustur(sayi);

    if(baslangic==NULL){

        baslangic=sonaekle;
    }
    else
    {

        struct node* temp=baslangic;

        while(temp->sonraki!=NULL){

            temp=temp->sonraki;
            temp->sonraki=sonaekle;
        }


    }

}

void yazdir(){


    struct node* temp=baslangic;

    while(temp!=NULL){


        printf("%d =>",temp->sayi);
        temp=temp->sonraki;
    }

}

int main()
{



    int secim, sayi;

    while(1){
        printf("1-Sona eleman ekle.....\n");
        printf("Yapmak istediginiz secimi yapin...\n");
        scanf("%d",&secim);


        switch(secim){

        case 1:
            printf("Hangi elemani ekleyeceksiniz..\n");
            scanf("%d",&sayi);
            sonaekle(sayi);
            yazdir();
            break;

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to do make linked list but when I run this code it gives output like this:`-443987883 =>`. What is my mistake. I can't find it. Thank you for your answers and giving your time.

Comment: My main language is turkish so secim means choice, sonaekle means addt the end

Comment: There are a lot of example code for linked lists. I think you should try to learn to debug and create a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

There are typos.

Instead of

```
baslangic=sonaekle;
```

where you are assigning the function pointer of the type `void ( * )( int )` to the pointer of the type struct `node *` you need to write

```
baslangic=sonaeklenecek;
```

Instead of this while loop

```
    while(temp->sonraki!=NULL){

        temp=temp->sonraki;
        temp->sonraki=sonaekle;
    }
```

you need to write

```
    while(temp->sonraki!=NULL){

        temp=temp->sonraki;
    }

    temp->sonraki = sonaeklenecek;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer my friend but sonaekle is a function but sonaeklenecek is a struct. How did this happen?

Comment: @Azqaf the compiler should issue a message that there are used incompatible pointer types.

Comment: It did not give any error. @VladfromMoscow

Comment: @Azqaf It is strange because the type struct node * and the type of the function pointer that you are used in your code  void ( * )(inti) are not compatible pointer types. At least the compiler should issue a warning.

Comment: @Azqaf If my answer has helped you to resolve your program then you can select the answer as the best answer. In this case your reputation will be increased.:)